# Unidirectional many-to-many insert using dynamic session in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, insert, many-to-many

I've the "AnagraficaBase" hbm file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class entity-name="AnagraficaBase" table="anagrafica">
<id name="ID" type="int" >
  <column name="ID" not-null="true" />
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="Email" type="string" >
  <column name="Email" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="true" />
</property>
<one-to-one cascade="all" class="NetCms.Users.User" property-ref="AnagraficaMapped" name="User" />
<joined-subclass entity-name="Anagraficaprova" table="anagrafica_prova" >
  <key>
    <column name="id_anagrafica_prova" />
  </key>
  <property name="data di nascita" type="DateTime">
    <column name="data_di_nascita" sql-type="DateTime" not-null="true" />
  </property>
  <property name="nome" type="string">
    <column name="nome" sql-type="varchar(25)" not-null="true" />
  </property>
  <property name="dropdown test" type="string">
    <column name="dropdown_test" sql-type="varchar(255)" not-null="true" />
  </property>
  <bag name="profilo" table="anagrafica_prova_custom_field_checkboxlist_values" cascade="all" fetch="select">
    <key>
      <column name="IDanagrafica_prova" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <many-to-many entity-name="CustomCheckboxListValue">
      <column name="IDcustom_field_checkboxlist_value" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-many>
  </bag>
</joined-subclass>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I want to create an "Anagraficaprova" object with dynamic session (EntityMode.Map).
As you can see, I've a unidirectional many to many relation between "Anagraficaprova" and "CustomCheckboxListValue".

So, when I do:

```
ISession mapSession = sess.GetSession(EntityMode.Map);

List<IDictionary> profiles = new List<IDictionary>();
Hashtable profilo1 = (Hashtable) mapSession.get("CustomCheckboxListValue",1);
profiles.add(profilo1);

Hashtable anagraficaProva = new Hashtable();
anagraficaProva.add("Email","test");
anagraficaProva.add("data di nascita", "08/10/1982");
anagraficaProva.add("nome","pippo");
anagraficaProva.add("dropdown test","1");

anagraficaProva.add("profilo", profiles);

mapSession.SaveOrUpdate("Anagraficaprova", anagraficaProva);
```

The anagraficaProva object is correctly saved, but the record in "anagrafica_prova_custom_field_checkboxlist_values" table (the couple: IDanagrafica_prova,IDcustom_field_checkboxlist_value) is not inserted.

Where is the problem?

Thank you...

Comment: have you checked that `profilo1` is not null?

Comment: Course I did!! profilo1 is not null!

Comment: Did you flush the session after SaveOrUpdate and still not in db? (`mapSession.Flush();`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else comes here.

NH inserts `AnagraficaBase` because it uses `identity` to get the id but batches the Inserts into table `anagrafica_prova_custom_field_checkboxlist_values` to insert them in one go later. But before they are sent to db the session is thrown away and therefor the batched Inserts.

`mapSession.Flush();` after SaveOrUpdate tells NH to send all pending statements.